# Optical slim-IDE drive into a slim-SATA notebook?

Tags: laptop, optical-drive, adapter

I would like to change the optical drive (slim-IDE) on my notebook with a slim-SATA one.
So far I have found only two solutions: to buy an external USB box or an adapter like this:
http://bilder1.eazyauction.de/currra/artikelbilder/3628.jpg

Sadly, this kind of adapter works only in a desktop environment, because it needs some power to turn it on (like a floppy disk drive), but I can't afford a whole power supply for just 5 volts...

So, do you know whether or not is it possible to attach a slim-SATA drive to a notebook with a slim-IDE connector?

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, it's physically / electrically possible - you need an adapter to translate the ATA commands from IDE<->SATA. Unfortunately there is almost no possibility that this will fit into the form factor. The one you've linked a picture of is similar to all the ones I've ever seen, and they will not fit inside the laptop.

If you were feeling very, very brave, you could try a mod to rewire it, but that would be a lot of work. Instead you should change your notebook drive for the one your laptop was designed for, or else change the notebook.